# Why is my output always the same despite different inputs

Tags: java, boolean

I want to make the output state that its a leap year if the year is divisible by 4 or 400 but no matter what year I input, both inputs come out.

```
public class LeapYear {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = Comp122.getInt("Please enter a year");
    System.out.println(isLeapYear(year));
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    boolean leapYear;

    leapYear = true;  
    if (year % 400 == 0 || year % 4 == 0);{
        System.out.println("It is a leap year");
    }
    else if (year % 400 != 0 || year % 4 != 0);{
        System.out.println("It is not a leap year");
    }
    
    
    return leapYear;
}
```

Comment: if (year % 400 == 0 || year % 4 == 0); <- take the ; out . You have an extra ";" after the conditionals

Comment: And note that `leapYear` will always stay `true`, you never assign anything else and therefore always return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, you are adding `;` at the end of your `if` expression which terminates `if` blocks body. `;` after `if` are usually used for one liner statements. Ideally you should `{ ... }` blocks for `if` statements. So your code would look like:

```java
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 400 == 0 || year % 4 == 0) {
        System.out.println("It is a leap year");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("It is not a leap year");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Bdw, JDK also provides a utility method to check this in case you don't want to do it yourself:

```java
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return java.time.Year.of(year).isLeap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers just tell you to fix a typo, but none figured out that *your entire algorithm is broken!*.

> a leap year if the year is divisible by 4 or 400 but no matter what year I input, both inputs come out.

Any number that is divisible by 400 is by definition divisible by 4. Your if check is pointless. That is **not** the leap year algorithm.

The algorithm is this:

If the year is not divisible by 4, it isn't a leap year. If it is, but it is also divisible by 100, but it is not divisible by 400, then it is not a leap year either. Otherwise, it is a leap year.

In other words:

```
if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)) {
   ....
}
```

And, yes, a semicolon is itself a statement that does nothing. This:

```
if (false); {
    System.out.println("HELLO!");
}
```

prints, because you are saying: "If false, do this: ;", which does nothing, and then you are saying: "I have a block, please execute it" (this is legal java), and thus hello is always printed. [A] Do not put that semicolon there, [B] when you editor indents that block at the same level as `if`, don't think: "What kind of dumb editor is this thing?", but think: "Hmm, maybe I'm doing something wrong".

Comment: LOL, you are right, I just look at the question from the compiler point of view